# parentNode undefined in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to insert a new element using a chrome extension.

```js
const oldEl = selector;
const parentEl = oldEl.parentNode;
const newEl = document.createElement('');

parentEl.insertBefore(newEl,oldEl);
```

I'm always getting the error message `"Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"`.
However if I just use `console.log(parentEl)` before inserting the Element it works.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome but I don't think this can be answered without a reproducible demo.

Comment: It looks like const oldEl is undefined. What is in the selector variable that is being assigned to oldEl? It would be helpful if you gave more details.